# Yii Framework 2.0 Migration with existing database

Tags: php, database, migration, reverse-engineering, yii2

I know the concept of Yii framework 2.0 migrations. Let's say we generate migrations source code and run the command, the database tables will be created based on the source code. Is it  possible to create migrations source code based on the existing database? With source code I do not mean the model, the controller or the CRUD classes but I mean the migrations source code. It is some kind of reverse engineer.

Answer (score 11):

The following yii2 extension generates migration scripts from an existing MySQL, MSSQL, PgSQL or SQLite database:

[www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-migration-utility/](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-migration-utility/)

Source: [www.github.com/c006/yii2-migration-utility](http://www.github.com/c006/yii2-migration-utility)

Answer (score 4):

I found a way that create migration from existing database tables.first install this extension from [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-migration-creator) via `composer require bizley/migration`.Then copy below code to your `config/console.php`:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migration' => [
        'class' => 'bizley\migration\controllers\MigrationController',
    ],
],
```

then in your command line type `php yii migration/update table_name` for single table or
`php yii migration/create table_name1,table_name2,table_name3` for multi tables or `php yii migration/create *` for all tables.

Comment: This extension works well and is current. Cannot thank the author of this extension enough for such a wonderful and useful creation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such functionality out of the box in Yii 2. Otherwise it must be menthioned in documentation and framework features.

And it's not trivial functionality to implement because of variety of RDMS. You can create issue on [Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues) about that (but check if something similar already exists before that), but its unlikely will get high priority.

Answer (score 0):

My practice is to mysqldump out a sql file, remove all unnecessary data, and put it in your source code, plus some migrating files, that way we can get the full schema of the system.